# Angular ng-pattern for input=text

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, angularjs-directive

I have an Input tag of type text that I can't change to number. (Kendo UI generated)

I am trying to set the **ng-pattern** on it to restrict it to 1,2,3,4...99. Basically more than 0. 0 is bad.

This just gives me 1,2,3,4...9

```
 ng_pattern="/^[1-9]$/"
```

How do I get 12,23,45 etc up to 99 too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
\b([1-9][0-9]{0,1}|100)\b
```